# How to make follow path with gcode imported?

Tags: animation

I am using the plugin: https://github.com/blender-for-science/import-G-code to import Gcodes. When I import the gcode I convert it to curve and then I create a nozzle and it follows the path. The problem is that the path of gcode is made by multiple curves (hundreds), from infill lines, to shell lines etc etc. How can I make the nozzle move between one line to the other and so on, to simulate the 3D print animation?